# Which database should I choose? MySQL or mongoDB?

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb

I'm working on a project which is somewhat familiar to WhatApp, except that I'm not implementing the chatting function.

The only thing I need to store in the database is user's information, which won't be very large, and I also need an offline database in the mobile app which should be synced with the server database.

Currently I use MySQL for my server database, and I'm thinking of using JSON for the syncing between mobile app and the server, then I found that mongoDB has a natural support for JSON, which caused me wonder should I change to mongoDB.

So here are my questions:

1. Should I change to  mongoDB or should I still use MySQL? The data for each user won't be too large and it does have some requirement for data consistency. But mongoDB's JSON support is somewhat attractive.
2. I'm not familiar with the syncing procedure, I did some digging and it appears that JSON is a good choice, but what data should I put into the JSON files?

Comment: Another option is MariaDB.

Comment: mysql is relational db, mongodb is not, so you must think about this. if you just wanna store json objects in a database, i think you better use mongo

Comment: @d1mitar Thanks, but I won't store json objects in a database, I only use json for the syncing procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually flagged this as too broad and as attracting primarily opinion based answers but I'll give it a go anyhow and hope to stay objective.

First of all you have 2 separate questions here.

1. What database system should I use.
2. How do I sync between app and server.

The first one is easily answered because it doesn't really matter. Both are good options for storing data. MySQL is mature and stable and MongoDB although it's newer has very good reviews and I don't know of any known problems which would prevent it from being used. So take the database which you find easy to use.

Now for second I'll first put in a disclaimer that for data synchronization between multiple entities entire books are written and that it is after all this time still the subject of Phds.

I would advice against directly synchronizing between mobile app and database because that requires the database credentials to be contained within the app. Mobile apps can and will be decompiled and credentials extracted which would compromise your entire database. So you'll probably want to create some API which first does device/user authentication and then changes the database.

This already means that using MongoDB for sake of this would probably be a bad idea.

Now JSON itself is just a format of representing data with some structure, just as XML. As such it's not a method of synchronization but transport.

For synchronizing data it's important that you know the source of truth.
If you have `1 device <-> 1 record` it's easy because the device will be the source of truth, after all the only mutations that take place are presumably done by the user on the device.

If you have `n devices <-> 1 record` then it becomes a whole lot more annoying. If you want to allow a device to change the state when offline you'll need to do some tricks to synchronize the data when the device comes back online. But this is probably a question too complex and situation dependent to answer on SO.

If you however force the device to always immediately propagate changes to the database then the database will always contain the most up to date record, or truth. Downside is that part of the app will not be functional when offline.

If offline updates don't change the state but merely add new records then you can push those to the server when it comes online. But keep in mind you won't be able to order these events.

Comment: then the device is the source of truth for "new" items. And the server is source of truth for "other" devices. And you can simply push them from `1 device -> server -> n devices` without problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For the syncing part, I check my design, and it turns out most the syncing pattern is **1 device <-> 1 record -> n devices**, it's somewhat like an SNS: I changed my profile, then the modification is synced to the server, as well as all my linked friends. For now, I think I'll keep using MySQL until some major problems are found, and I think I have a little understand about the syncing procedure. Thanks again for you answer, it helps a lot.

Comment: I think the **server -> other devices** part is quite clear, however, I may make modification both in the app and the server(by a web page, maybe), then I should use a timestamp or something to compare the data between app and the server, is that correct?

Comment: In most cases timestamp will work just fine for this yes. But keep in mind that you can't be certain that the timestamp on the device is correct. Someone could have his time off by a couple hours due to timezones/daylight savings/plain wrong settings etc.